# Simple PHP query question: LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

When I replace

```
$ordering = "apples, bananas, cranberries, grapes";
```

with

```
$ordering = "apples, bananas, grapes";
```

I no longer want cranberries to be returned by my query, which I've written out like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * from dbname where FruitName LIKE '$ordering'";
```

Of Course this doesn't work, because I used LIKE wrong.  I've read through various manuals that describe how to use LIKE and it doesn't quite make sense to me.

If I change the end of the db to "LIKE "apples"" that works for limiting it to just apples.  Do I have to explode the ordering on the ", " or is there a way to do this in the query?

Comment: What does the data look like that you are querying? Can you make an example?

Comment: just to help you out, this is a mySQL query called via PHP, not a PHP query. A common mistake though!

Answer (score 8):

LIKE is normally used for partially matching strings, e.g. you'd use

```
WHERE fruitname LIKE 'app%'
```

to find 'apple' and 'apples'.

What you (probably) want is the IN clause, e.g.

```
WHERE fruitname IN ('apples', 'bananas', 'grapes')
```

Answer (score 2):

It probably should be:

`SELECT * FROM database WHERE FruitName IN ('apples','bananas','grapes')`

Answer (score 2):

try using

```
SELECT * from dbname WHERE FruitName IN ('apples','bananas','grapes')
```

if you need the result to be in the same order as the IN list extend the query with and ORDER BY

```
SELECT * from dbname WHERE FruitName IN ('apples','bananas','grapes') ORDER BY FruitName
```

Comment: (Avoid double quotes for SQL string literal delimiters. The ANSI standard delimiter is the single quote; double quotes only work in MySQL, and then only for the default `SQL_MODE `setting.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to explode the string and convert it to the appropriate SQL. This is probably the SQL syntax you want to end up with:

```
SELECT * FROM dbname WHERE FruitName IN ('apples', 'bananas', 'grapes')
```

PHP code:

```
$fruits = array();

foreach (explode(', ', $ordering) as $fruit) {
    $fruits[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($fruit) . "'";
}

$fruits = implode(', ', $fruits);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbname WHERE FruitName IN ($fruits)";
```

Comment: Wait, when I do this, I get an error message that the [] operator on this line: "$fruits[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($fruit) . "'";" is not supported for strings.

Comment: Careful if you edit the code, `$fruits` starts out as an array and turns into a string after the implode().